# Inability to open the link or click on the text button to go to the reletad area on the website with selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

website's javascript code:

```
div class="display-actions">==$0
<a class="show-all" href="/acount/previous_orders" data-yslinktracking="mainpage:previous_orders:all_previous_orders">All Previous Orders</a>
```

Hello friends, There is a text on the website called "All Previous Orders". I want to click this automatically, but I couldn't.
When I hover the mouse over this text on the website (All Previous Orders), https://www.websitename.com/acount/previous_orders appears at the bottom corner of the page. I need to find and click the link or there could be another solution to click this text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code has worked:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300)") #move the area
order= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='All Previous Orders']")        
order.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
previousOrder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='All Previous Orders']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",previousOrder)
previousOrder.click()
```

Comment: The program is giving an error named  ElementClickInterceptedException. Above the code is only scrolling the window down

Comment: ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a class="show-all" href="/acount/previous_orders" data-yslinktracking="mainpage:previous_orders:all_previous_orders">...</a> is not clickable at point (697, 6). Other element would receive the click: <div class="row">...</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer CSS over XPATH then, you can use the below css_selector :

```
a[href='/acount/previous_orders']
```

and click it like this :

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/acount/previous_orders']")))
).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: I am getting an error named TimeoutException  I tried both 10 seconds and 20 seconds ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 10 or 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/acount/previous_orders']")))
).click().perform()

Comment: where is this element present in UI ?

Comment: this item is available as text at the bottom of my orders window, but when this window is opened, the texts about the restaurant names that have been placed on the mouse appear in the preview box.  Preview box may prevent click process

Comment: Can I have the URL ?